# Fall Foliage in Southern California

Tags: southern-california

What are some of the best places in Southern California (max. of 2 hours drive from LA) to enjoy Fall colors. Also, most places I have seen being recommended are hike trails. Are there any places in which I can enjoy fall colors without much of hiking, or even better a scenic drive loop?

Comment: SoCal is a desert.  But that being said, http://www.californiafallcolor.com  , https://www.kcet.org/socal-wanderer/the-7-best-spots-for-fall-color-in-california etc etc  Try google "fall foliage map California"

Comment: Compared to New England or the Upper Midwest, the West does not offer much in the way of fall foliage, because it is too dry. In California, you will only find stands of deciduous trees in urban areas where they are irrigated (i.e. in people's yards) or near the handful of streams and rivers. The forests are overwhelmingly dominated by pines, firs, and other evergreens. If you want fall color without hiking, fly to Wisconsin or New Hampshire.